# Vue3 Redirect with dynamic property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I have this configuration in my `router.ts`:

```js
{
  path: "/admin/operations/job-allocation/:id",
  name: "JobAllocation",
  component: () =>
    import(
      "@/views/admin/operations/job-allocation/index.vue"
    ),
  children: [
    {
      path: "",
      redirect:
        "/admin/operations/job-allocation/:id/operatives",
    },
    {
      path: "/admin/operations/job-allocation/:id/operatives",
      name: "JobAllocationOperatives",
      alias: "Operatives",
      component: () =>
        import("@/views/common/Operatives.vue"),
    },
  ]
}
```

When I visit the path: `/admin/operations/job-allocation/1` I want to go to `/admin/operations/job-allocation/1/operatives`.

But in this setup it goes to `/admin/operations/job-allocation/:id/operatives` (the :id as a literal string of ':id' instead of being replaced by the number 1.

I'm hoping to use the router to do this, instead of using a 'mounted' hook to do the redirect at the JobAllocation component.

Is this even possible? I did not find this senario in the official Vue3 Router docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the object form of `redirect` to specify the route by name, so that the parameters are automatically passed along:

```js
export default createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/admin/operations/job-allocation/:id',
      name: 'JobAllocation',
      props: true,
      component: () => import('@/views/admin/operations/job-allocation/index.vue'),
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          redirect: {
            name: 'JobAllocationOperatives', 
          },
        },
        {
          path: '/admin/operations/job-allocation/:id/operatives',
          name: 'JobAllocationOperatives',
          alias: 'Operatives',
          component: () => import('@/views/common/Operatives.vue')
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-redirect-to-named-route?file=src/router.js)